# How to map a field to a new instance of a class?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm writing an ASP.NET Core WebAPI project and have a problem with mapping. Since I cannot create collections of primitives in Entity Framework Core, I created an entity that stores needed primitive. But on the upper layers I don't really need a separate class with a primitive. Is it possible to create a Map from a class to a primitive(for comfort using) and back(to store them in DB)?

**Realtor.cs**

```
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ICollection<PhoneNumber> Numbers { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Photo")]
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }
    public Image Photo { get; set; }
}
```

**PhoneNumber.cs**(that class with primitive)

```
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(13, MinimumLength = 10)]
    public string Number { get; set; }
```

**Realtor.cs**(on business layer)

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Numbers { get; set; }
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }
    public Image Photo { get; set; }
```

So what i need here is to bind an `ICollection<PhoneNumber>` to `ICollection<string>`. Or will it be better not to do such way?

Comment: When you just need a list of phone numbers, then use ICollection<string> for that. When you want to extend your phonenumbers in future, go with your ICollection<PhoneNumber> approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to map *to* an `IEnumerable<string>` for display and such, but if your adding or modifying, you should stick with a `List<PhoneNumber>`. This is because the PK for each phone number will be crucial. Otherwise, you'll end up adding new (i.e. duplicate) phone number records, instead of modifying existing ones.